# Playwright , Failure in After hook , fails test

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

In Playwright , I have grpup of 4 tests executed under same  describe  , in aftereach I close tabs to go home page , Intermittently sometimes steps in afterEach fails , it marks test  as failed , is there any configuration to avoid it

Thanks
Gayathri

```
test.describe("Playwright", () => {
    test.beforeAll(async ({browser}) => {
        Login to application
        go to home page
    });

test("File menu", async () => {
 validate file menu}); 

  test("Edit menu", async () => {
     validate Edit menu});

  test("Tools menu", async () => {
     validate Tools menu});

  test.AfterEach(async ({browser}) => {
            go to home page
        });
```

After executing test 2 , if after each , it makes test2 as failed

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Please share a more realistic code sample. It's impossible to debug from pseudo-code.

Comment: sorry I cannot post any detailed step ,  but after hook fails , element is not clickable , which makes test status as failed in runner screenshot is saved. Intermittently  there will be toast message in Home tab , (so I need to wait for 1min, ) thanks